# schengen visa refusal for italy

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, visa-refusals

I applied for schengen visa C type for Italy for 20 days. My father was sponsoring my trip. I attached following documents along with visa application:

- medical insurance ,
- passport,
- sponsor letter,
- sponsor account statement,
- guarantee letter from my father that I will come back to my country,
- hostel bookings,
- flight itinerary,
- letter of employment,
- payslips,
- application for leave from office,
- pictures.

Purpose of my trip was tourism.

Embassy has refused the visa and stated that “there is no assurance of me coming back to my country and purpose of my visit is not clear“

Comment: What sponsor are you talking about? Do you mean your father? Are you living with him? Would he be travelling with you? Are you employed (i.e. are you talking about your payslips or his)?

Comment: `no assurance of me coming back to my country` Did you provide your booked itinerary or only your days of travel and places where you are visiting and your return tickets ?

Comment: You can add some info about your personal circumstances in order to clarify your question.  Where is your father based? Whose letter of employment? Your fathers?

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?

Comment: My father is my sponsor. i am living with him. he willl not be travelling with me . i am employed

Comment: i am from pakistan

Comment: father is based in pakistan

Comment: i showed my confirmed hostel bookings in my travel itinerary.

Comment: Those types of refusals are really hard to nail down without knowing your demographics and apparent life-style and performance history.  Close voting as 'unclear'